# Created my own PHP API

Tags: php, api

Hello StackOverflow community

Currently I'm in small project, where a API is required.
I tested some SOAP WSDL and restFul API's, but none worked for me. So I created my own API. As I'm not a professional programer, I want to know if my API is unsafe.

```
<?php

class API{

public function __construct(){
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
        if(!empty($_POST)){
            $data_array = array();
            require_once('PreparePOST.php');
            foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
                array_push($data_array,array($value => $key));
            echo new PreparePOST($data_array);
        }else{return new Exception('No Data Requested');}
    }else{return new Exception('Request not allowed');}
  }
}$init = new API();

?>
```

Some serious validation and security stuff is done after PreparePOST($data_array);
E.g. only allowed parameters and character escaping.

> Notice: This is only the POST implementation the GET implementation and an API Auth Token will be available later.

- What are you thinking?
- Is this compete nonsense?
- Where are possible security issues?
- How can I improove my code?

Btw. my project is a Tool, which transmits server infos from our customers (like HD capacity and backup logs) to our server, so we evaluate all server statistically.

Thanks for you advice
KR

Comment: Ok, si first of all, go check out [this](http://php.net/manual/en/security.php), and just read everything, it should give you some help! 

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you say that the `PreparePOST` object does validation and security it would be ideal to share that code too to identify security issues.

One thing which springs to mind right away although not a security issue is that you should `throw` an `Exception` rather than `return` one. Also when you are initializing your API object you don't have any way to catch the exceptions which it may throw. See the `try catch` block which I've put below.

Also the code isn't super readable, perhaps this would be better:

```
<?php
class API
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
        {
            if(!empty($_POST))
            {
                $data = array();

                require_once('PreparePOST.php');

                foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
                {
                    array_push($data, array($value => $key));
                }

                echo new PreparePOST($data);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception('No Data Requested');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception('Request not allowed');
        }
    }
}

try 
{
    $init = new API();

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    //handle the exception here
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Specific coding style is down to preference however to keep it readable and maintainable you should definitely make good use of whitespace. There's absolutely nothing gained by keeping code bunched together. In fact quite the opposite.

I wouldn't say there's a need to call your `$data` variable `$data_array`. You can see from the code that it's an array, also separate arguments to functions with a comma and a space for readability `,`. (When calling array_push).

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot.

Comment: If you feel it helped, please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the tick below the number of votes it has received (to the left of the answer).